# Were there any experiments that produced rocket fuel grade methane on mars?

Tags: mars, spacex-starship, raptor, methane, moxie-oxygen-generator

One of the main reasons that SpaceX's Starship engine raptor uses methane is because it can theoretically be produced there from atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> and subsurface H<sub>2</sub>O.

Where there any experiments that produced methane rocket fuel on mars?

Something similar to what [MOXIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Oxygen_ISRU_Experiment) hopefully will do with Oxygen.

Comment: @uhoh I will edit my question, the focus of the question is whether or not any experiments managed to produce methane rocket fuel on Mars. It doesn't matter from which source materials on Mars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, while a variety of institutions have looked at producing Methane on Mars by combining native CO2 with imported H2 using the [Sabatier Reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction), no experiments have actually been carried out on the planet.

Backup evidence:

- NASA's [In Situ Resource Utilization](https://www.nasa.gov/isru/overview) talks about MOXIE but does not have any information on methane-based experiments
- Same on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ_resource_utilization)

Answer (score 2):

The closest to this that has been done was tests to create methane in a vacuum chamber set up to simulate the atmosphere of Mars. The details of this are talked about in the book by Robert Zubrin, "The Case for Mars". It should in theory work on Mars, but the only ISRU instrument that has been sent to Mars is to make oxygen, and that is on its way now on Perseverance.

Comment: Do you know of any plans to send such an experiment to Mars on future missions?

Comment: There is nothing really planned, except for SpaceX's Starship missions, which I'm certain will be testing that in the early days to have a full scale plant when they actually land humans there.

Comment: It would be fairly surprising if the Sabatier reaction didn't work. The only problem I can see is filtering dust and fines from the Martian atmosphere without the filter clogging. Otherwise its just standard gas chemistry.   Mining ice is much more challenging because of all the mechanical problems getting to it, drilling, etc.

Comment: The dust is certainly something to consider. I suspect the MOXIE tests will do something similar. Also, MOXIE tests several of the same things that are needed for making rocket fuel, after all, a good chunk of the fuel is liquid oxygen for a methalox system!